# Understanding Angular FormBuilder with Groups and ngModel data and how/if they can be used together?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-ngmodel, angular2-ngmodel, angular-formbuilder

I am running into some issues with trying to use `FormBuilder` in my Angular app and how I can set the default values in the form based on my `ngModel` data.

In my class, I have the following code:

```
form: FormGroup;

constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
) { }

ngOnInit() {

    this.form = this.fb.group({
        category: ['', [Validators.required]],
        quantity: [1, [Validators.required]],
        size: ['', [Validators.required]],
        title: ['', [Validators.required]],
    });
}
```

When I look at the `{{ form.value | json }}` in my template, it shows the original values with the empty values. So I decided to try to set the default values in the FormBuilder group like this:

```
    this.form = this.fb.group({
        category: [this.item.category, [Validators.required]],
        quantity: [this.item.quantity, [Validators.required]],
        size: [this.item.size, [Validators.required]],
        title: [this.item.title, [Validators.required]],
    });
```

But I am given these errors:

```
ERROR Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. 
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'category')
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')
```

This is my template for the form:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
        <ion-item lines="none">
            <ion-label position="stacked">Category</ion-label>
            <ion-select [(ngModel)]="item.category" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
                <ion-select-option *ngFor="let category of categories" [value]="category">
                    {{ category }}
                </ion-select-option>
            </ion-select>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item lines="none">
            <ion-label position="stacked">Title</ion-label>
            <ion-input [(ngModel)]="item.title" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item lines="none">
            <ion-label position="stacked">Size</ion-label>
            <ion-input [(ngModel)]="item.size" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item lines="none">
            <ion-label position="stacked">Quantity</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="number" [(ngModel)]="item.quantity" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>

    </form>
```

Any thoughts what is wrong with my approach and how I can get the default values from my `this.item` to appear in the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zerospi, the problem is that you create the form before you has data in your variable "item" - this is the reason you don't see the value

1. NEVER Mix together Reactive forms and Template-Driven (ngModel)

   The use `[(ngModel)]="variable" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}` it's ONLY to get an input that **not belong** to the FormGroup.

   e.g you can has a "checkbox" to show a new input. Some like

   ```
    movil:boolean=false;
    form=new FormGroup({
      phone:new FormControl()
      mobile:new FormControl()
    })
    <form [formGroup]="form">
      Phone<input formControlName="phone">
      <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="movil" 
              [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}">Mobile
      <input *ngIf="movil" formControlName="mobile">
    </form>
   ```

   Well, really we use

   ```
      <input type="checkbox" [ngModel]="movil" 
              (ngModelChange)="movil=$event;!$event && form.get('mobile').setValue('')
              [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}">Mobile
   ```

   To "clean" the FormControl "mobile" if we uncheck

   How control a FormGroup?
2. In general we can have a function in the way

   ```
   getFromGroup(data:any=null)
   {
      data=data || {phone:'',mobile:''}
      return this.fb.group({
         phone:[data.phone,Validators.required]
         mobile:data.mobile
      }
   }
   ```

   And use

   ```
   this.form=this.getFormGroup(this.item) //if we have an object "this.item"
   this.form=this.getFormGroup() //if we want an empty Form
   ```
3. Another approach is create the form an use patchValue()

   ```
   this.form=this.fb.group({
      phone:['',Validators.required]
      mobile:''
   }
   this.form.patchValue(this.item)
   ```
4. To avoid initial errors (e.g. we create the form after a call to an API), sometimes is util use some like

   ```
   <form *ngIf="form" [formGroup]="form">
   ...
   </form>
   ```
5. Remember that a FormControl is disabled, don't showed in form.value, you need use form.getRawValue()

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 approaches regarding forms: Template driven (more logic in `.html` and Reactive (more logic and control in `.ts`). With `formBuilder` injected and `[formGroup]="form"` you went for reactive approach which is more spread among experienced devs and tends to be more comfortable since it gives more control over your forms.

It is not a good practice to use two-way data binding with this approach. You should put `formControlName="controlNameXYZ"` to the according input field and do that for all your input fields defined when building form.

Don't forget to have `ReactiveFormsModule` inside `imports` array of your module (or `AppModule` if you only have one in whole application).